# SAP B1 WOOCOMMERCE Plugin

Tags: woocommerce, e-commerce, integration, sapb1

We are integrating new features for our plugin "[Woocommerce SAP Business One](https://www.pasarelasdepagos.com/shop/global/woocommerce-global/woocommerce-sap-business-one/)".

Now we are looking to integrate some externals in the whole process, however we want have control of the connector from SAP side.

Can we create a new connectors or only use SAP layers is possible?

Please give some advise thanks.

Create our own connector for SAP Business One from the SAP side to replace business layer.